# How to name the concept of the mean shift divided by the standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standard-deviation, mean, standardization, quality-control

In the context of a paper dealing with Statistical Quality Control, I am defining and using the concept of the mean shift divided by the standard deviation of a (normally distributed one-dimensional) random variable, which is

$\delta\; =\; \frac{\left|\;\mu_0-\mu\;\right|}{\sigma_0} \text{,}$

where $\mu_0$ and $\sigma_0$ are the desired or initially assumed values for the population mean and standard deviation, respectively, and $\mu$  represents the real value for the population mean.

I have named $\delta$ the ***standardized deviation*** of the random variable, but this name has been rejected by the paper reviewer, as it is too close to the term *standard deviation* but represents a rather different concept.

So my question is **how do you name the concept of the mean shift divided by the standard deviation of a one-dimensional random variable?** Is there a standard name for it? If not, how would you call it?

EDIT: The parameter $\delta$ can be described as the deviation of the mean in *sigma* units.

Comment: In the context of one-sample testing, your formula is called _effect size_, where `mu0` is null-hypothesis value of the mean, `mu` is the observed value, `sigma` is the assumed population st. dev.

Comment: Thank you, @ttnphns. In this case, I am thinking of *population* values, rather than of *sample* terms, although I think it could also apply.

Comment: Call it (relative) shift size.

Comment: Why not *standardized mean deviation* ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, the problem with standardized mean deviation is, maybe, that it is still too similar to standard deviation... Anyway, my first question was if there is a standard specific name for that concept.

Comment: Standardized mean difference: http://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Effect%20sizes%20based%20on%20means.pdf

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, you may want to publish it as an answer.